# Install mysqlclient-python in Docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker, debian

I am trying install mysqlclient-python in docker with Debian 8 
but when I run python3 setup.py install 
I get error:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.cpython-34m.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tryed install various packages (openssl, crypto++, libmysqlclient-dev, mysql-client,...) but nothing helped me.. 
Do you know what exactly I need?

Comment: To solve that error, try `$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev` or `$ sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev`.

Comment: this packages I have installed but don't works

Comment: What was the procedure you followed?

Comment: Or did you try to pip install?

Comment: I runned your commands and then: `pip3 install mysqlclient`
in docker.  If you want, I can send you my Dockerfile and docker's bash_history

Comment: It should install without issues with pip, was there some error and if so, what  was it?

Comment: Now I runned it with command: `pip install mysql` or download project from github and tryed install with `python setup.py install` but error is same.. here is my full output: http://pastebin.com/ALtR6CGC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `-lssl` and `-lcrypto` are failing, you're likely missing the libssl headers

On debian-based systems you can install these with

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Most likely you'll already have an `apt` line in your `Dockerfile` which installs `libmysqlclient-dev`, you'll simply add `libssl-dev` to the list of packages there.